# Is it possible to open Google Maps with an intent that has multiple pins

Tags: android, google-maps

Without using the Google Maps API (only launching the maps app with an intent) is it possible to contain multiple coordinates, and therefor have multiple pins on the map that opens? This does not mean creating a rout between two points.

How I do it for one pin:

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q="+ Lat + "," + Longitude + " (" + name+ ")";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is impossible. There does not seem to be a way to pass multiple points in through the Geo URI string, and therefore this must be accomplished by using the Google Maps API. I wish it were possible, it would make a lot of simple map tasks much easier to accomplish, but alas.

Link to the intent spec (which does not include any way to pass multiple locations)
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: Yes it is possible here it goes you can collect the latitude and longitude as to display pin on the map we need Latitude and Longitude , so in which activity you are display the Map simple give a call to the collected Latitude and Longitude , hope this answer well

Comment: Can you provide code? It seems from reading the APIs and experimenting that the Geo URI intent only accepts a single location, not any sort of list of locations